# Multithreading stack, vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, multithreading, stack, push

I'm writing this multithreading class to use std::vector as a stack.
I don't know why it is not working.

If a thread makes a pop and no element is in the stack, it should wait until a new push is completed.

```
void StackAdder::addToStack(std::wstring s)
{
    insertLock.lock();
    stack[laststring] = s;
    laststring++;
    insertLock.unlock();

    cv.notify_all();
}

std::wstring StackAdder::removeFromStack()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m);
    cv.wait(ul, [this]() { return (numstring > 0); });

    std::wstring s;
    insertLock.lock();
    laststring--;
    s = stack.at(laststring);
    insertLock.unlock();

    return s;
}
```

declared here:

```
class StackAdder
{
public:
    StackAdder();
    ~StackAdder();
    void addToStack(std::wstring s);
    std::wstring removeFromStack();
private:
    std::vector<std::wstring> stack;
    int laststring;
    int numstring;

    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex m;
    std::mutex insertLock;
};
```

Running this program I get exception "vector subscript out of range"

Comment: Please show the declarations of all the involved member variables.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `vector::push_back` rather than indexing when adding to  the stack? Or at least checking to see if the `std::vector` needs to increase it's size(and doing something about it)?

Comment: @RichardCritten trying to use vector::reserve i get the same exception

Comment: Why do you have both `numstring` and `laststring`?  What's the difference between them?

Comment: In the code shown you never resize the `vector` in any way?  Note that [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) does not change the size of the `vector`.

Comment: @NPE i didn't remember to remove one of them

Comment: @G.M. I reserved in the costructor 100 positions to avoid out of range, but doesn't work. But I think you are meaning something different

Comment: Even after using `reserve` you still need to `push_back`.  Array elements between `size` and `capacity` (reserved) do not yet exist and can not be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments above, I got that vector uses size and capacity updated through push_back method.
To avoid that, I used reserve and resize method in the constructor.

```
   StackAdder::StackAdder()
    {
    laststring = 0;
    numstring = 0;
    stack.reserve(100);
    stack.resize(100);
    }
```

Comment: Just resize would be adequate here.